# Proof of equal angles in a quadrilateral.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

points E and F are given on side BC of a convex quadrilateral ABCD (with E closer than F to B). Suppose angle EAB = angle CDF and  angle FAE = angle FDE. Prove that angle CAF = angle EDB.

Comment: Please draw a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given that angle $FAE$ = angle $FDE$ so this means that $AEFD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

We will succeed in showing that angle $CAF$  = angle $EDB$ if we can show that angle $BAC$ = angle $BDC$, in otherwords if we can show that $ABCD$ is also a cyclic quadrilateral.

The picture here is, I hope, self-explanatory
[image]

Comment: Nice. So if two circles cut, the outer segments of any traversal subtend same angle at opposite intersection points  making $ FAC =EDB.$

Comment: That would appear to be the case, yes

Comment: (Not related, a generalization).  I wonder how it would be if three or more circles are concurrent at points $A,D.$

Comment: Sounds like there is another question waiting to be asked